# jquery returning name and value of radio button on click event

Tags: jquery, radio-button

when a user clicks on a radio button, i want to set the value of a textbox in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ratdon/q3RNe/1/) with the name and value of the radio button which is clicked.

my script is:

```
$(function () {
    $("#radio").buttonset();
    $("radio").click(function () {
        $("#did").val = ($(this).attr('name') + "=" + $(this).val);
    });
});
```

where #did is the input textbox.
but my code isn't doing that. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.val()` like a variable, you cannot assign to it. it's a function, call it!

Also, `$("radio")` looks for the html tag `<radio>`

So for example:

`$("#did").val(($(this).attr('name') + "=" + $(this).val()));`

Comment: You can actually pass the value to the `.val()` function. You just cannot do the `=` assignment.

Comment: Sorry, forgot we were working with radio buttons. Good edit! Glad it works.

Comment: Changing `$("radio").click` to `$("#radio").click` as you suggest will not work with the code given. It needs to be changed to a selector that matches the radio buttons instead of the div as shown in my answer.

Comment: Yeah what does it need to be.. `$("input:radio")`?

Comment: both `input[type='radio']` or `input:radio` will work fine. but don't know whose performance is good.

Comment: See my answer under point 2, the two better options are there.

Comment: I just read "Because :radio is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :radio cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="radio"] instead." So there we go

Answer (score 1):

Two issues as pointed out already, but both of which are causing your code to not work:

1) You are using `.val` as a property but it is a function. Thus you need to change this line

```
$("#did").val = ($(this).attr('name') + "=" + $(this).val);
```

to

```
$("#did").val($(this).attr('name') + "=" + $(this).val());
```

2) You are binding the click event to an element that doesn't exist (`<radio>`). You need to change your selector to something like `input[type='radio']` or `input[name='radio']`.

Here is [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3RNe/3/) which implements both of these changes.

Comment: can you say which one's performance is good?
`input[type='radio'] ` or `input:radio `

Comment: `input[type='radio']` performs much better in modern browsers.

Answer (score -1):

`this` refers to the global context. You have to user `$(event.target)` instead.

```
$("radio").click(function (aEvent) {
    $("#did").val ($(aEvent.target).attr('name') + "=" + $(aEvent.target).val());
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` does not refer to the global context within an event bound via jQuery, it refers to the element that triggered the event.